# On dativ and akkusativ

Tags: dative, accusative

"Ich gratuliere dir zum Geburtstag." 
"Ich rufe dich an." 
In both sentences the other party is "receiving" the action, so why is one dativ and the other akkusativ ?
Thank you!

Comment: In SW Germany and Switzerland you will also hear "Ich rufe *dir* an" - Maybe shows best that there can be no strict rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts about giving/receiving (dativ) or accusing (accusative) just give a first hint. The actual case is defined by the verb. Some verbs need their object in dative case, some in accusative case, and some even in other cases.

- The verb *»gratulieren«* needs its object in dative case.

  > Ich gratuliere **dir.**
- The verb *»anrufen«* needs its object in accusative case.

  > Ich rufe **dich** an.

In fact there is no logic behind. Just stubborn verbs that have individual requirements.

Comment: That's ... impractical to say the least. Thank you.

Comment: Verbs are as stubborn with the cases of their objects as nouns are with their genders.

Comment: Oh and does that mean that the indirekt objekt can be non dative too? Maybe with some "dative direkt objekt" verbs?

Comment: *Ich nenne ihn einen Lügner* - Both objects accusative. That is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use the terms direct and indirect objects in German

Comment: Better to leave "accusing" out of this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like "receiving an action" may give you a first hint, but it is not sufficient to decide the case, you have to learn that together with the verb.

Compare

> Ich gratuliere dir.

with

> Ich beglückwünsche dich.

or

> Ich frage dich.

with

> Ich antworte dir.

Comment: It's still unclear putting it like that, for all the sentences I can only see the other party as the direkt objekt.

Comment: @archaic, the answer is: Because this is how "gratulieren" works, which a dictionary will tell you.

Comment: So there's no logic behind it?

Comment: Not the sort of logic you're looking for. You need to learn the ruled case with the verbs.

Comment: @archaic, you can come up with rules, but like all good grammar rules they will have exceptions ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Wikipedia says "The dative case (...) is a grammatical case used in some languages to indicate, among other uses, the noun to which something is given." This can be helpful in very many (of course not in all) cases. I think it works for '*gratulieren*'.

'As time goes by', learners will understand that there are clusters of verbs having correspondant intern and extern structures:

- *jemand**en an**rufen* like *de**n** Fernseher **an**stellen, jemande**n** bei der Polizei **an**zeigen, jemande**n an**sehen/**an**schauen, de**n** Drucker **an**schließen* ...

but!

- *jemand**em** das Salz = **etwas an**geben* like *jemand**em etwas** zu trinken **an**bieten, jemand**e**m de**n** Drucker **an**schließen, jemand**em etwas an**sehen (z.B. sein**e** Enttäuschung) ...* [person = dative, non-person = accusative]

In the same way you say _jemand**em etwas be**scheinigen.

However, contrary to the general dative rule you say

- *jemand**en be**glückwünschen* like *jemand**en be**raten, jemand**en be**urteilen, jemand**en be**ruhigen, jemand**en be**grüßen, jemand**en be**waffnen ...*

but!

- *jemand**em** bevor**stehen*** like _jemand**em** in nichts nach**stehen**, jemand**em** zur Seite **stehen**, jemand**em** gut zu Gesicht **stehen**, jemand**em stehen** *(Kleidungsstück)*, *jemand**em** im Weg **stehen**, ein**er** Sache entgegen**stehen** ...*

It could be very useful to have a catalogue and a hierarchy of those structures and sub-structures, but I don't know if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

For Akkusativ you are asking "wen oder was": **wen oder was** rufe ich an?

That works, but this one doesn't: wen oder was gratuliere ich zum Geburtstag?

Correct it would be "**wem** gratuliere ich zum Geburtstag" and thus it is Dativ.

Hope that helps.

Comment: And why is it wem not wen? It's still "Who do I congratulate...?"

Comment: This "ask a question" exercise does rarely play well with learners. It only works if you know what to ask.

Comment: In terms of direkt objekt and indirekt objekt I simply can't seem to clearly differentiate them in the "Ich gratuliere dir ..." sentence, because literally translated it's "I congratulate him" so he's the direkt objekt ...

Comment: I should look at it more as gratuliere = "to give" congrats ?

Comment: Diese Antwort hilft niemandem, der aus einer Sprache kommt, in der es weder Dativ noch Akkusativ gibt. Die Wen/Wem-Frage hilft nur Leuten, die bereits ein sicheres Gefühl für diese beiden Fälle haben. Für jemanden, der Probleme mit diesen Fällen hat, sind »wen gratuliere ich« und »wem rufe ich an« genauso plausibel wie die korrekten Fragen.